# How to use regex in bash for selecting a string between double quotes?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I really searched this kind of question among the other similar questions here but couldn't find any answer.

I have the following text in a file:

```
TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "8755asd-"
```

I am trying to grep the following (the double quotes can include numbers, characters and special characters):

```
TYPE_C = "8755asd-"
```

The grep command that I am using is this: `grep -o "TYPE_C = \"[0-9a-zA-Z-]*\"" text.txt`

However, I think the regex in this command is not generic.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by is not generic?

Comment: I mean it may not include many possibilities. Not a general solution.

Comment: @KasiyA I already made my comments for all answers and selected one of them.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​Good! But your own command is still generic(general).

Comment: No it is not because as I wrote to one of answers below: I think this can be a problem in a different scenario that if there is a single quote between double quotes then this will not work.

Comment: Doesn't this work? `grep -o 'TYPE_C = "[^"]*"' text.txt` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex which matches the corresponding `TYPE` only if the double quotes contain all the characters you mentioned . That is, atleast a character, atleast a number, atleast a special character.

```
grep -oP 'TYPE_[A-Z]\s*=\s*"(?=[^"]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^"]*\d)(?=[^"]*[^"\w])[\W\w]*?"' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mU4fK5/1)

Example:

```
$ cat ri
TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "8755asd-"
TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "875d"
TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "asd-"
TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "875-"
$ grep -oP 'TYPE_[A-Z]\s*=\s*"(?=[^"]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^"]*\d)(?=[^"]*[^"\w])[\W\w]*?"' ri
TYPE_C = "8755asd-"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's@.* TYPE_C = "\([0-9a-zA-Z-]*\)".*@\1@p' text.txt
```

That is, `-n` to not print lines that don't match.  Then replace the entire line with the part in double quotes after TYPE_C, and `p` to print the result:

```
8755asd-
```

Comment: In your example, you use the same regex that I use. I think this can be a problem in a different scenario that if there is a single quote between double quotes then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut to get the same output if the pattern remains the same.

```
echo 'TYPE_A = "1" AND TYPE_B = "6" AND TYPE_C = "8755asd-"' | cut -d"\"" -f6
```

Comment: No, the pattern doesn't remain same.